# Formato Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**PROBLEMA**

Tengo un problema al retornar los resultados de una consulta, dado que requiero ordenar los resultados de una consulta en un solo `array` en JavaScript, y no un `array` con sus objetos siendo cada objeto un array diferente.

**CODIGO**

```
$scope.tableDatos= datosObtenidos.data;
      var countRegistro = [];
      $scope.tableDatos.forEach(function(registro, index) 
      {
          countRegistro.push([registro.Registros]);
      });
      console.log("Registro: ", countRegistro);
```

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO**

[image: Array]

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

[image: Array Esperado]

> **Nota:** El dato esperado lo realicé con un array sencillo que fue
>   declarado con ese orden.

```
$scope.datos = [
        ["1", "3118"]
      ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quitale los corchetes al push y se soluciona el problema amigo =)

```
$scope.tableDatos= datosObtenidos.data;
  var countRegistro = [];
  $scope.tableDatos.forEach(function(registro, index) 
  {
      countRegistro.push(registro.Registros);
  });
  console.log("Registro: ", countRegistro);
```